# search and print a word from a file

Tags: regex, bash, search, awk

I am trying to capture a word with a static search string.

Search String: **customfield_12345**

Here is the source file that i am trying to feed to awk script:

Infput file: abc.log

```
{"expand":"hello,foo,boo,doo","id":"546546","self":"http://localhost/abc/rest/api/latest/issue/12345","key":"abcd-4567","fields":{"customfield_12345":"$D21.0/dfgdf/string_to_capture_from_file "}}
```

Query: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^customfield_12345/){print $i}}}' abc.log`

Expected output: **string_to_capture_from_file**

I thought to use combination of grep and cat, but somehow option "-o" is not supprted on all  platforms.

Comment: If you add `print NF;` right before your `for` loop, you will notice `awk` only detects 2 fields. This is because default `awk` takes fields as separated by a character included in `IFS` (space, tab or newline). As you have only 1 space in your line, there are only 2 fields

Comment: @Ploutox can you suggest me the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is not the best tool for your case. Figuring out the relvant separators might be a pain, and using a JSON parser as suggested by the other answer would be easier.

However, in your specific case, you can modify your query as follow :

```
MYVAR=awk -F'":"|","|{"|"}' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/customfield_12345/){i++;print $i}}}' test
echo ${MYVAR##*/}
```

`-F` allows us to set `":"`, `","`, `{"` and `"}` as internal fields separators. When awk encounters one of those patterns, it will split the line in several columns.

This will return `$D21.0/dfgdf/string_to_capture_from_file`, which you can later parse with bash using `echo ${MYVAR##*/}`

Comment: The reason I wanted to choose awk instead of python is because, I want to execute this command thru ant script, If had to put Python and Json i have configure build.xml to get the binaries for Python with Json.

Answer (score 1):

Your input file contains a JSON string, so I would parse it as JSON instead of using a regex:

```
python -c "import json;json_data=open('abc.log');data = json.load(json_data);print data['fields']['customfield_12345'];json_data.close();"
```